# Video element jumping in CSS3 multi column layout

Tags: html, css

Im using a CSS3 multi column layout on my website with in the second column a video element.
This works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but in Safari the video jumps to below the columns.
Can i fix this and why does it happen?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Provide at least an example of your code, please. This sounds like an overflow problem, maybe try adding `overflow: auto;` to the second column.